# Xcode 6 UIimageview display error

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

Guys i have a problem. So i just make a autolayout in xcode (background image and over the background image i have a logo image uppercase and in the middle i square where i will want to import from database a random image)

As you can see in the Mainstoryboard(preview) on the 4 displays those image look exacly the same. Instead of this i would like to display them on the same way as i have on the 3rd resolution (4.7 inch), because under the image i want to put something else and on the 3.5inch is to small the space and on the 5.5 inch is to big, i want the image to be bigger...

Comment: Just so I understand... you want the space underneath the square image to  always be greater than or equal to a specific size? The square image should resize itself to ensure that happens?

Comment: yeah man .. something like this.. i try to fix how guys told me but i cant figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You could add height constraint on UIImageView which displays random image relative to the height of main view (root view for UIViewController)

In IB control drag UIImageView to the root view, you will see a popup, click on Aspect Ratio. You could set aspect ratio of UIImageView height to the height of root view. You could set another constraint to make width and height equal to make it square.

This will give you space relative to height of screen below UIImageView.